# How to override url_for_event in Apotomo to always include a parameter?

Tags: cucumber, subdomain, apotomo

To get to run Cucumber with my app and subdomains, I [read](https://gist.github.com/643a758320a2926bd2ed) that I should add default parameters to the default_url_options.

However, I can't seem to find a way to add default parameters to the `url_for_event` helper that Apotomo gives. I believe this would be the first (if not the only) step to getting integration tests, Apotomo, and subdomains to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an [answer from Paul Hagstrom in the Apotomo mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/cells-and-apotomo/browse_thread/thread/fdc695115a414855):

```
class YourBaseWidget < Apotomo::Widget 
  def default_url_options 
    ... 
  end 
end 

class YourOtherWidgets < YourBaseWidget 
  ... 
end
```

This works a lot like how most of your Rails controllers inherit from `ApplicationController`. Thus, anything you apply to `ApplicationController` will apply, by inheritance, to your child controllers.